# Every subspace $W$ from $V$ when $\dim W = \dim V -1$ is kernel of a non null linear form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I must prove that every subspace $W$ from $V$ that satisfies $\dim W = \dim V -1$, is the kernel of a linear form.
First of all, I don't get what this mean. It's saying that, for example:

$\operatorname{span}((1,0,0),(0,1,0))$ which is a subspace of $\operatorname{span}((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1))$

is the kernel of a linear form?

How to understand it, and prove it?

Comment: In the above, $\phi(x) = x_3$ will work. $\ker \phi$ gives the space spanned by $e_1,e_2$ the first two unit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the subspace $W$ has one less dimension than $V$. Think of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To construct the function, start with a basis for $W$, extend it to be a basis
for $V$ and then use this basis to define a suitable function. To define a linear function, we need only specify its effect on a basis.

Suppose $\dim V = n$ and let $x_1,...,x_{n-1}$ be a basis for $W$. Choose
$x_n \in V\setminus W$ and show that $ x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n$ is a basis for $V$.

Define $\phi(x_k) = 0$ for $k=1,...,n-1$ and $\phi(x_n) = 1$.

Check that $\ker \phi = W$. We see that $W \subset \ker \phi$ by definition.
Suppose $\phi(x) = 0$, and let $x=\sum_k\alpha_x x_k$. Then
$\phi(x) = \alpha_n \phi(x_n) = \alpha_n$ and so $\alpha_n = 0$ from which
we have $x \in W$.